# Which project is more mature, ScalaQuery or Squeryl?

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, scalaquery, squeryl

For me both of them looks quite similar if it's going to features, but it's hard to say without using them (yet). So I have few questions:

1) Are they really feature comparable (more or less)? 
2) Is there any example of enterprise or big open source system using any of them? 
3) I have impression that Squeryl have better documentation, is lack of documentation in case of ScalaQuery real problem? 
4) Which of them is growing faster and/or is faster on fixing the bugs? 
5) Is any of them easier to use / more productive?

Comment: See slide 46 and forward http://scalaquery.org/doc/ScalaQuery_Commerzbank_2011.pdf

Comment: I see, so ScalaQuery will get commercial support, nice! Do you maybe know when it will be officially part of the stack?

Comment: See this thread https://groups.google.com/group/scalaquery/browse_thread/thread/3a285d610ff05b95/80915f768fd61214?lnk=gst&q=SLICK#80915f768fd61214

Comment: Why close this thread? ScalaQuery and Squeryl with time will be for Scala frameworks (Play, Lift,...) what GORM is to Grails and AR to Rails and LINQ-to-SQL (or lightweight EF) to .NET. SIQ & SLICK slides look incredible, and yet, zero roadmap. @kuki's question is absolutely valid, he wants to know where to invest his time & energy -- Scala SQL solutions to-date are not exactly M$ LINQ-esque

Comment: @virtualeyes Exactly. I would like to see more posts here from people who were using ScalaQuery or Squeryl (or both in ideal case), especially when as you said there is virtually no real info about SLICK. Maybe vote for reopen then? ;)

Comment: 7 [to close] against 2 to re-open, the odds are not good. BTW, ScalaQuery is under active development in-house at TypeSafe now.  Big things in the works (think a true JVM-based LINQ). ScalaQuery will be rebranded as SLICK.  As for when we, the masses, will see SLICK, TBD, can't imagine anytime soon, sounds like a huge endeavor. In the meantime, I suspect ScalaQuery will remain in its current form hovering in .9 to 1.0 range while Squeryl will progress.  Unfortunate since Squeryl and SLICK will invariably take different approaches, thus, again, the validity of your question, which to choose ;-)

Comment: I guess I'll wrote to guys from Typeasafe to ask if they have any precise plans for SLICK, and if ScalaQuery will still be maintained or whole effort will go now into SLICK. In meantime maybe more votes for reopen will appear ;)

Comment: I can only answer (2) by saying that Lift has support for Squeryl and people using it are very happy with it.

Comment: @kuki Some updates ?! Is it confirmed that Slick will be included in the Typesafe stack ?

Comment: Yes :) Stefan Zeiger (creator of ScalaQuery) was officially hired by Typesafe (http://www.linkedin.com/pub/stefan-zeiger/2b/885/256) and first release of SLICK is already out: https://github.com/slick/slick/wiki. You can also take a look at this presentation from Scala Days 2012: scalaquery.org/doc/ScalaDays2012-SLICK.pdf